# Import, parse and display csv in react

Tags: reactjs, import, read.csv

What is the best way to import, parse csv(100 thousand rows) and display it like excel table in react.js ?

Basic Requirements:

1. Read CSV(40k- 100k rows)
2. Parse and Display
3. Map and rename columns

I want to do this using React.

Please help to find the solution.

Partial solution https://codesandbox.io/s/qlj338vnkj,